# How can i convert jdk-8u74-linux-x64.rpm to 1.8.0_74 to check java version?

Tags: java, version

I am installing `jdk-8u74-linux-x64.rpm` on the server using a script. To download, I have parameters names like this:

```
"java": {
    "version": "8u74",
    "minor_version": "b02"
}
```

How can I use these these two parameters to verify if java is installed or not? I do not want to introduce another parameter like `java_version=1.8.0_74-b02`. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's unclear what you're talking about.  Are you asking how to how to match these against the output of `java -version`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworthYes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ruby you can solve your problem. You can use below code to do that:-

```
def parse_app_name (filename, minor_version)
    file_name = filename.split('/')[-1]
    if file_name =~ /^(jre|jdk).*$/
      major_num = file_name.scan(/\d/)[0]
      update_num = file_name.scan(/\d+/)[1]
      # pad a single digit number with a zero
        if update_num.length < 2
          update_num = "0" + update_num
        end
      app_name = "1.#{major_num}.0_#{update_num}" + "-" + minor_version
    else
      puts "error"
    end
    return app_name
end
```

Execute:

```
puts parse_app_name("jdk-8u92-linux-x64.rpm", "b14")
```

Output:

```
1.8.0_92-b14
```

Existing java version:

```
$ java -version
 java version "1.8.0_92"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

Checking the existing java Version:

```
system('java -version', :out => ['/tmp/log', 'a'], :err => ['/tmp/log', 'a'])
puts File.read("/tmp/log").split("\n")[1].scan(/\d.*/)[0].chomp(")").eql? parse_app_name("jdk-8u92-linux-x64.rpm", "b14")
```

Output:

```
true
```